# Asp.Net MVC Assign roles when user registeration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to Asp.Net MVC and working on register and login forms. I have created MVC default application and as you know it came with built-in Member Ship tables for `Users, User Roles, User Claim, User Login and Roles`.

I've created 2 Roles in `Roles` table **Normal User** & **VIP User**

Right now I've copied and paste same `Resgiter` ActionMethod in `AccountController` and assigned roles upon resgietration.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> NormalUser(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Normal");
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                // Send an email with this link
                string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult VIPUser()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> VIPUser(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "VIP");
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**View** this view code is for NormalUser, I've same view code for VIPUser also. and model classes are default.

```
@model FypStore.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Template.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("NormalUser", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new {              @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<h4>Create a new account.</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

For above code, I had to create 2 Views, which means 2 forms.  1 for Normal User and 1 for VIP User.

How can I do this in 1 form ? I mean only 1 from with Username, Password, Confirm Password fields with extra field of 2 Radio Buttons `o VIP  o Normal`. Whichever role a user select, assign it to him and register.

Comment: you  can change your RegisterViewModel and add an additional field like IsVIP user, in your form add a @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsVIPUser)... you get the idea

Comment: @SadiRubaiyet yeah, thanks. and then pass that value in the controller and assign role. ?

Comment: yes, something like UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, model.IsVIPUser  ? "VIP" : "Normal"

Comment: @SadiRubaiyet what would be the datatype of IsVIP in RegisterViewModel ?

Comment: I would prefer an enum, it gives you the flexibility as you add more roles. But for your checkbox a bool makes more sence

Comment: @SadiRubaiyet Your idea helped me. Thanks :)